# R Hosmer-Lemeshow error in model.frame detault

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 119 observations from patients and 565 variables. There is some NA in my variable of interest for my regression linear model.
I did first my linear regression model :

```
RL1 <- glm(x~Var1+
         Var2+
         Var3+
         Var4, Dataframe, family = "binomial")
summary(RL1)
enteexp(coefficients(RL1))
```

and then :

```
library(ResourceSelection)
hoslem.test(Dataframe$x, fitted(RL1), g=4)
```

But I have this answer :

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(y0 = 1 - y, y1 = y) ~ cutyhat)
```

I have try with na.omit on the Hoslem test but also it doesn't work... Someone could help me ?